# ANCOVA controlling for a categorical manipulated factor

Tags: r, anova, categorical-data, repeated-measures, ancova

I have an experiment where 6 subjects performed 20 different lifting tasks `LT` with 3 different knee braces `KB`. The emg activity `emg` of the rectus femoris is the dependent variable and `LT` and `KB` are independent within factors. I am only interested in the effect of the `KB` on the emg activity. Additionally, for some subjects there is quite some amount of missing data.

So i wanted to conduct a two-way repeated measure Anova. However when using all 20 `LT` the results of the p-values are NaN. I guess this is because there are not enough degrees of freedom caused by the missing data.
My next idea was to conduct a one-way repeated measure ANCOVA with `LT` as the covariate. However i am not sure if an ANCOVA is appropriate in this case. I need to mention that i am not too familiar with ANCOVA and i only found detailed information about it when using continuous covariates.
I am doing my statistical analysis with R. The syntax i used is the following. However i am also unsure whether the syntax for the ANCOVA is correct.

```
ANOVA: anova_test(data = data, dv = emg, wid = PatientID, within = c(KB,LT), type = '3')
ANCOVA: anova_test(data = data, dv = emg, wid = PatientID, within = KB, covariate = LT, type = '3')
```

I also tried the ez package with ezANOVA() which gives me completely different results. Here i only got an effect for `KB` wheras for anova_test() i also got one for `LT` and for the interaction of `KB:LT`.

```
ezANCOVA: ezANOVA(data, dv = emg, wid = PatientID, within = KB, within_covariates = LT,type = 3)
```

I would greatly appreciate your help in determining whether an ANCOVA is appropriate for my data, or if you could recommend sources with more information on performing an ANCOVA with categorical data and how to do it in R.